# Debugging an API using AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using php to build a web API for an iOS app. I'm not very good at it. As I go, I like to `echo` stuff to help me debug.

If I attempt to access one such API using AFNetworking 2.0, how can I log the echo string? Is there some property of the `AFHTTPSessionManager` `POST` response I can access? None of the below is useful:

```
[self POST:@""
    parameters:params
       success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
           NSLog(@"success");
       }
       failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
           NSLog(@"%@", task.response);
       }
];
```

Note that this is a json API so `echo` causes the failure callback to run, not the success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log the response from the server:

```
NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned it is a json API so when I echo I am not getting  a success callback, but a failure: `NSDebugDescription = "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.";`

Comment: Then instead of `echo`-ing your message, put your message in an array and `echo` it by using `echo json_encode($array_with_message)`;

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
   [self POST:@""
parameters:params
   success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
       NSLog(@"success");

      //log the response string here 
      NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

   }
   failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
       NSLog(@"%@", task.response);
   }
];
```

Comment: Sorry, see edit above - my content type is json so `success` is not called.